# Automation of seeding parameter store during the first deploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, aws-parameter-store

I'm using a serverless framework in my nodejs project. In the project I have in the yaml definition of services. I want to created RDS database and pass the password and admin name. I'm using AWS System Manager (Paramter Store) for keeping these credentials. During the deploy I download this credentials from parameter store to create rds by the script I wrote in nodejs

Definition of rds instance:

```
Resources:
  DatabaseCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      DatabaseName: ${file(resources/rdsName.js)}
      Engine: aurora
      MasterUsername: ${file(resources/rdsUsername.js)}
      MasterUserPassword: ${file(resources/rdsPassword.js)}
      Port: "3306"
```

Sample script for retrieving the database password from parameter store:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const getrdsPassword = async stage => {
  const ssm = new aws.SSM();
  const params = {
    Name: `RDSPassword-${stage}`,
    WithDecryption: true,
  };
  const password = await ssm.getParameter(params).promise();
  return password.Parameter.Value;
};

module.exports = serverless => {
  const {
    service: {
      provider: { stage },
    },
  } = serverless;

  return getrdsPassword('dev')
};
```

The problem is then, when the first deploy, i.e. creating the entire stack, I need to have password parameters and database username created in the parameter store. I would like to automate that when we do deploy, if specific parameters are not created, they are created and saved in the parameter store. (I want to be able to retrieve this data later to plug in a program to the database and view the data, debug)

I thought that I would write a script and with the help of `serverless-scriptable-plugin` before deploy I would run a script that checks if there is the data in the parameter controller that I will need for deploy, if it is not there it will create it. But browsing https://gist.github.com/HyperBrain/50d38027a8f57778d5b0f135d80ea406#file-lifecycle-cheat-sheet-md I wanted to plug into the event `before: package: cleanup:` and check it there, but unfortunately before running the script when deploying serverless framework is giving me an error:

```
 Parameter Not Found ------------------------------------

  ParameterNotFound: null
```

A piece of the serverless.yml file in which I use the script:

```
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  service: ${opt:service, self:service}
  scriptHooks:
    before:package:cleanup:
      - scripts/bootstrappingParameterStore.js
```

The question is if there is an earlier event that I can plug in with this plugin and start checking the paramteter stora and using it if it doesn't find the data I need?

Alternatively, is there any other simpler way to automate the first deploy, create RDS with a password and get this data manually somewhere later?